# Show and hide a div when element isin-viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want `<div class="sticky-info">` to hide when a `<span class="waar">` is in the viewport. When `<span class="waar">` leaves the viewport I want `<div class="sticky-info">` to hide.

The first part hide `<div class="sticky-info">` works fine but second part show `<div class="sticky-info">` doesn't. Probably it's something really stupid but I'm not that JS wizard. Here's the JS.

```
<!--sticky info-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.waar:in-viewport')) {
        $('.sticky-info').hide();
    } else {
        $('.sticky-info').show();
    }
});
</script>
```

The page you can visit here
http://www.joets.be/test/joetz/page_vakanties.html

Thx

Comment: 1) Are you using this? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport I have never heard of :in-viewport so I assume you are. 2) Your question is odd, you want to hide an element when it is outside of the viewport i.e. it is not visible anyway? That is normal browser behaviour. How will the user know the element is hidden? Or perhaps you plan to fade them in/out.

Comment: Yes it's that viewport.js I use.
And indeed, it's the other way around. Hide when in viewport, show when out viewport.

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: OK, but in your page, currently neither .waar nor .sticky-info exist. Might need some basic html and css, but I will create a jsfiddle for testing.

Comment: OK see here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/3c5w0gbs/ you can add and edit this fiddle and update the version. I think an issue you are going to have is that if you have multiple instances of .waar or .sticky-info then you need to target this instance of one of them. i.e. $(this);

Comment: *Hide when in viewport, show when out viewport.* - What's the point? Why not just always hide it?

Comment: It's not the same element. When A is out, show B. When A is in, hide B.

Comment: @MDC I missed that, apologies.

Comment: It only makes sense as sicky-info has position:fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if statement will always be true. `$('.waar:in-viewport')` will return a jQuery object, empty or not, it doesn't matter, it is a truthy value.

I believe what you are looking for is `.is()`:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($('.waar').is(':in-viewport')) {
        $('.sticky-info').hide();
    } else {
        $('.sticky-info').show();
    }
});
```

*Note: This assumes that your plugin supports the same functionality as native jQuery pseudo selectors..*

Comment: Yes this works. Your code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/3c5w0gbs/7/ I was going mad as it was always returning true.