# jQuery change css on a specified element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

I need something that will change the style of a div when you scroll to a specific element

Example:

In my header i have the texts:
1) Home
2) Text2
3) Text3
4) Text4

When on top i want the "Home" to be white and all the others blue
When on paragraph 1 i want the "Text2" white and all the other blue
When on paragraph 2 i want the "Text3" white and all the other blue
When on paragraph 3 i want the "Text4" white and all the other blue
When below "Text4" i want the "Home" to be white and all the others blue

PS: "Text2","Text3" and "Text4" will have nothing else in betwheen

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28397804/if-element-is-in-viewport-stop-scroll-animation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show and hide a div when element isin-viewport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366422/show-and-hide-a-div-when-element-isin-viewport)

Comment: Pls provide an example for what you need. Your question is not clear. And the edit makes it more confusing...

Comment: Hope the new edit makes it clear, completely re-written

Comment: Does the first text have fixed positioning or something? So that's it's always visible. To be honest, the new explanation doesn't make things much clearer.

Comment: Yes it does have fixed positioning

Comment: Okay, with the final edit of the question it makes more sense. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This toggles the color of any header text at the point a matching element comes into view (or leaves) :

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYXgdB?editors=001)

```
$(function() {

var gate = $(window),
bar = $('header'),
title = bar.find('span'),
element = $('.element'),
viewin, viewout;

gate.on('load resize', function() {

    viewin = []; viewout = [];

    element.each(function() {

    var placement = $(this).offset().top-gate.height(),
    dimension = $(this).outerHeight();

    viewin.push(placement);
    viewout.push(placement+dimension);
    });
})
.scroll(function() {

    var location = gate.scrollTop();

    element.each(function(i) {

    var option = title.eq(i), white = option.hasClass('white');

    if (location > viewin[i] && location <= viewout[i]) {
    if (!white) option.addClass('white');
    }
    else if (white) option.removeClass('white');
    });
});
});
```

Comments below are no longer very relevant because they are discussing an earlier stage.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt change to normal when you scroll back

Comment: Have a look with developer tools, it definitely does. You can see it best when gently using the scrollbar if you're on a browser that doesn't do a smooth scroll. The change is made when the element touches the bottom. But it depends a lot on when you'd like to switch the color exactly. Here's an example where the change is around the middle of the screen and it's more visible : http://tinyurl.com/pqt9zwu.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) or with [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr). There are plenty of tutorials about skrollr so dont worry.

Comment: try to give a little explanation of why the OP should use those libraries rather than simply the links

Comment: Can you give me a little help with the waypoints please?
I cant get it to work

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

1. Use **[`scroll()`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)** to listen scroll event
2. Get the scroll top value by using **[`scrollTop()`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)**

**DEMO :**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('#div2').css('color', $(this).scrollTop() > 390 ? 'red' : 'blue');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=main style="height:1000px">
  <div id=div2 style="margin-top:500px">element</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following jquery functions

- **[`scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)**
- **[`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)**
- **[`offset`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/)**
- **[`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**
- **[`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

Your code could look something like that:

```js
( function( $ ) {
    
    $(window).scroll(function(e){

        var home = $('#home');
        var switchPosition = $(window).scrollTop() + parseInt(home.css("top"))+30;
        
        $('.text').each(function(){ 

            if ( switchPosition > $(this).offset().top &&
                 $(this).attr('data-color') !== home.attr('data-color') ) {

                home.css({color: $(this).attr('data-color')});
                home.attr('data-color', $(this).attr('data-color') );

            }            

        });

    });

} )( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="home" style="font-weight: bold; color: blue; position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;">HOME</div>
<div style="color: white; position: fixed; top: 170px; left: 20px;">scroll down...</div>

<div class="text" data-color="blue" style="background: #999; height: 500px"> </div>
<div class="text" data-color="red" style="background: #666; height: 500px"> </div>
<div class="text" data-color="white" style="background: #333; height: 1000px"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Animating colors does not work unless you include a library for animating colors.
**jQuery does not animate colors** by default.

So for color-animation you must include library like **[JQuery UI](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js)**, but it is **large for just using color-animation.**

Instead i would suggest you to use [Bitstorm:ColorLibrary](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js), it's just **2.7kb** in size.

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hdyq15am/2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var top = document.getElementById("css_text").scrollHeight; // top position of '#css_text'
    alert("Top position of #CSS_TEXT : " + top);
    var calcu = top - 20;
 $(window).scroll( function(){
     var pos = $(window).scrollTop();
     if(pos >= calcu)
     {
  $("#css_text").animate({"color":"red","opacity":"1"},2000); 
     }
 });
});
```

```css
#css_text
{
    opacity:0;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors-min.js"></script>

<h1>HTML Ipsum Presents</h1>
        
<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

<h2>Header Level 2</h2>
        
<ol>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ol>

<blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p></blockquote>

<h3>Header Level 3</h3>

<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
</ul>

<pre id="css_text"><code>
#header h1 a { 
 display: block; 
 width: 300px; 
 height: 80px; 
}
</code></pre>
<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
```